# How to write Arabic in plain luatex

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, arabic

I tried to write Arabic in plain Luatex but all letters in isolted mode

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\amiri={file:amiri-regular.ttf:mode=harf;script=arabic} at 12pt
\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \textdir TRT \pardir TRT
\amiri
 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

\bye
```

Comment: You need luahbtex for mode =harf. Did you use it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no I thinked there is no differ between luatex ver 1.14 and luahbtex. but as you told I was wrong. After compiling with lauhbtex it is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mode=harf (Harfbuzz) you need as engine `luahbtex`. So your log should start like this:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) ...
```

In texlive you get it with calling `luahbtex`

Then your example will give this:

[image]