# arabic text inside latin document in LuaTex (not LuaLaTex)

Tags: luatex, arabic, arabluatex

I try to typeset arabic text inside a latin document (english or german) in LuaTex.

I searched the web and many forums, but most of the answers are for (Lua)Latex (e.g. using arabluatex). I am writing plain LuaTex documents and cannot use LaTex-like features.

I tried to use arabic ttf-fonts (Amiri, ...) in combination with the text direction features (\textdir TRT) with direct arabic input in my (utf-8-)document. I see the arabic letters in my output, but of course as lingle letters and not with the arabic-like ligatures.

Is there any software working with plain LuaTex (1.10.0) which i do not have to compile myself? (I am working on both Ubuntu and Windows)

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618035/54817